# Convergence of sequence of functions $ f_n(x)=\begin{cases} n^{p+1}x & \text{if $0≤x≤1/n$}\\ \frac{1}{x^p} & \text{if $1/n<x≤1$} \end{cases} $

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, uniform-convergence, pointwise-convergence

**Question**: Let $p$ be positive real number and consider the sequence $\{f_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ defined by

$$
f_n(x)=\begin{cases}
         n^{p+1}x & \text{if $0≤x≤\displaystyle\frac1n$}\\
        \displaystyle\frac{1}{x^p} & \text{if $\displaystyle\frac1n<x≤1$}
     \end{cases}
$$

Let $f(x)=\lim_{n\to\infty} f_n(x)$ where $x\in[0,1].$
Then

(i) find $f(x)$

(ii) Is $f(x)$ is Riemann integrable?

(iii) Is the convergence uniform?

**My attempt**: As $n\to\infty$ we have $1/n\to0$ and hence $x=0$. So I thought $f(x)=\lim_{n\to\infty} f_n(x)=0$ and hence $f$ is Riemann integrable. But, key says I am wrong. How to find $f(x)$? Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Notice that for $n$ large enough, $1/n\to 0$ so your function $f(x)=\frac{1}{x^p}$ for $0< x\leq 1$. In $0$ the function should be define as zero. So we have a function which is not bounded in its interval of definition so couldn't be Riemann integrable, for $p\geq 1$. For the case $0<p<1$ we have that the improper $\int_0^1 \frac{1}{x^p}dx$ converges (not really Riemann integrable, but I think for your purposes could be say yes it is.) Notice that for uniform convergence we should normally have $$ \lim_{n\to\infty} \sup_{x\in[0,1]}|f(x)-f_n(x)|=0$$ but in this case, each $f_n$ is bounded, but $f(x)$ is not bounded, it means that $$\lim_{n\to\infty} \sup_{x\in[0,1]}|f(x)-f_n(x)|=\infty$$ and the convergence is not uniform. Indeed, faster: as each $f_n$ is Riemann integrable, but its limit $f$ is not, then the convergence is not uniform.

Comment: Sir, when $1/n→0$  we have $x=0$ "why not"  $f_n(x)=n^{p+1}x=n^{p+1}0=0$ ?

Comment: @JohnOmielan that's right, I'm assuming p to be a natural number.

Comment: @AkashPatalwanshi Note $x$ is *fixed*. Thus, as $n \to \infty$, for any $x \gt 0$, the second part of the multi-part definition will eventually be used, and continue to be used for all larger $n$.

Comment: @JohnOmielan sir, is then convergence is uniform? May be not because if it is then $f(x)$ must be Riemann integrable?

Comment: Uniform Convergence $\implies$ Riemann Integrability

Comment: @AkashPatalwanshi consider accept the answer if this solves your problem.

Comment: @Valerin It has been too many years since I last studied, and used, most parts of calculus, so I'm generally quite rusty with it. I'm sorry I forgot the technical definition of [Riemann integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_integral) means $f(x)$ is actually never Riemann integrable on $[0,1]$. Nonetheless, as I earlier stated, and your answer indicates, the improper, limit integral of $\lim_{y \to 0}\left(\int_{y}^{1}\frac{1}{x^p}dx\right)$ does converge for $0 \lt p \lt 1$, so in a way it could be considered to be "integrable", but that is actually something somewhat different.

Comment: @JohnOmielan Yes, usually we work with bounded functions, when taking about Riemann integrals, but the improper integrals deals with unbounded functions, which could be considered as an extension, but they are not exactly Riemann integrals.